# jQuery getting wrong cursor position when scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm scaling the entire `<body>` using a **CSS scale transform**. The problem is that I get the wrong cursor position. I want to create a new div where the cursor is clicked but div is being created in wrong position.

```
$('body').css({transform:'scale(0.5,0.5)'});
```

Comment: A demo presentation could be helpful for understand situation.

Comment: $('body').css({transform:'scale(0.5,0.5)'});
$('#container').on('click',function()
{
$('<div />',{class:"sample"}).css({position:'absolute',top:e.pageY,left:e.pageX,height:'50px',width:'50px'});
});

I need to create a div in a cursor clicked position